# org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer maven dependency

Tags: dependencies, maven-2

I did not find the maven dependency for apache Tailer.

I added :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But it does not seem to be enough.

Comment: You need to say what error you are seeing so that folks can help ?

Comment: The error is that the line import org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer; is red-underlined and they offer me to create a new class/interface/… named Tailer.   Smoggers, your solution does not work for me, but thanks.

Comment: @Freddy1492 try with groupId value also set to 'commons-io'.

Comment: @smoggers, Yes, I did it but it does not work :/

Comment: @smoggers. Hum clever, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<groupId>` is now '**commons-io**' (same as the *artifactId* value) within the Maven repository.

So change it to that and the Jar file should be found and downloaded.
You could also try using a later version (later versions also now have 'commons-io' as value for groupId).

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

See [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io/1.3.2).